Doctrine MongoDB bundle and Symfony Forms: associating a DocumentType to a field
I'm wanting to refer to documents within documents in MongoDB. I've discovered via this page that the MongoDB bundle includes a DocumentType which can be used as a Form Type, similar to the EntityType for table based ORM queries.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-bundle/en/5.0/form_validation.html
However, telling you that it even exists is the beginning and end of the documentation. When I go to implement it, I get an error message: Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\DoctrineType::getCachedIdReader(): Argument #1 ($manager) must be of type Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager, null given, called in /var/www/clim_rep/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php on line 199.
I'm not sure what to do next. The documentation points out that, "DocumentType expects the DocumentManager name or instance passed with the document_manager option instead of em." But that's all it says. No examples, no further explanation, just that. Here is the content of my Form Type class:
UPDATED My method of including the class was flawed and I've figured out how to correctly include it through $options, however now I'm getting a new message, "Doctrine MongoDB Manager named 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager' does not exist" when it very much does?
<?php
/**
 * ReportType - This class is responsible for creating the form for all Reports
 **/
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form;

use App\Document\Partner;
use App\Document\Report;
use App\Document\State;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\PreSubmitEvent;
use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Form\Type\DocumentType;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

/**
 * ReportType
---------------------
 * This class is responsible for creating the form for the rental entity.
 **/
class ReportType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     *  buildForm -  This function is responsible for building the form for the rental entity.
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder - The form builder interface
     * @param array                $options - The options for the form
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $today = new \DateTime();
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('date', TextType::class)
            ->add('author', TextType::class)
            ->add('report_type', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextType::class)
            ->add('partners', DocumentType::class, [
                'class' => Partner::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'document_manager' => DocumentManager::class,
            ])
//          ->add('states', DocumentType::class, [
//              'class' => State::class,
//              'choice_label' => 'name',
//              'expanded' => true,
//              'multiple' => true,
//          ])
            ->add('dews_region', TextType::class)
            ->add('climate_region', TextType::class);
    }

    /**
     *  configureOptions - This function is responsible for setting the default options for the form.
     *
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver - The options resolver
     * */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => Report::class,
                'entityManager' => null,
            ]
        );
    }
}


bump Any takers? Has anyone used MongoDB with Symfony?

Ok, I've gotten a little farther. Here is an updated version of my code. I've found what appears to be the correct way to include the manager, but now I'm getting the error message that "Doctrine MongoDB Manager named "Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager" does not exist." when it very much does.


I'm bumping this again because I just put it in what I hope is the correct tag to get responses.
